# conditional jump to an absolute address x86

Tags: gcc, assembly, x86

I want to do a conditional jump (with `JNE`) to an **absolute** address.
I compiled the following code with GCC and got the following error:

```
{standard input}: Assembler messages:
{standard input}:8: Error: operand type mismatch for `jne'
{standard input}:13: Error: operand type mismatch for `jne'
```

Does anyone know how to solve it? I also tried not storing the address in the `ebx` register, but to jump directly to the address with no success.

```
mov ebx, dword [0x8048593]
mov eax, [ebp+var_88]
cmp eax, 0x23 #check if the first char is #
jne ebx
lea eax, [ebp+var_88]
add eax, 1
mov eax, [eax]
cmp eax, 0x21 #check if the second char is !
jne ebx
add eax, 1
mov [esp+0x98+var_98], eax
call 0x80485B1
push 0x80485AE
ret
```

Comment: You just need to reverse the condition to skip a normal unconditional jump. `je skip; jmp ebx; skip: ...`

Comment: @Jester  Unfortunately, It's not a very likely solution for me. As you can see in my code, I am addressing a local variable which will no exist in the function skip..

Comment: If you check the insn set reference, you'll see that conditional jumps only have rel8 and rel32 encodings.  Only unconditional jumps have other options.  Also note that you can `jmp dword [0x8048593]` without loading it into `ebx` first.  And you can `cmp byte [ebp+var_88], '#'` instead of doing a 4B load.  For your next sequence, you can do `cmp [ebp+var88+1], '!'`.  Or do a 4B load into `eax`, then `cmp ax, '#!'`, instead of comparing each byte separately!

Comment: It's not a different function ... it's just a label so you can skip the `jmp`. Doesn't affect locals.

Comment: @Jester I thought so too, but then when I compiled it I got the following error:                                                                                                              'In function `skip':(.text+0x15): undefined reference to var_88'

Comment: Just means `var_88` is not defined, that's unrelated to the change. The error message just mistakes `skip` for a function, but that's harmless.

Comment: Use `.skip:` as the label name so it's a local label (and won't get a function-level symbol-table entry)

Comment: @Jester and Peter ,Thank you both. I put the value of var_88 instead of using var_88 and did what Jester said. It worked.